# как ускорить замену данных в экселе через питон или через что то другое

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

Сразу к делу! написал код и столкнулся с проблемой долгой работы цикла, ну как долгой в принципе нормальной, но есть большое НО данные тяну из pandas df следующего примера:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и данных там аж на 6800 строк из которых 600 файлов и 1200 листов. изначально цикл проходил по каждой строке и по подсчётам это бы заняло 25 часиков, код ниже проходит циклом по листу и скорость увеличилась до 15 часов что тоже очень много! Любые идеи как максимально ускорить процесс группового изменения ячеек в файлах эксель! всем спасибо!

```
import shutil
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import os
import re
from datetime import datetime
import tkinter as t
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import Tk, filedialog
from openpyxl.utils import column_index_from_string
def change_rows():
old_year = entry.get()
current_year = entry_1.get()
data = pd.read_excel('lib_new.xlsx', 'Замена', engine='openpyxl', index_col=[0, 1, 2, 3])
data = data.replace('=', '^', regex=True)
data = data.stack(dropna=False).reset_index()
data = data.rename(columns={'level_4': 'Регион', 0: 'Значения'})
data['имя_файла'] = data.apply(lambda row: row['имя_файла'].replace('XX', str(row['Регион'])), axis=1)
data['имя_файла'] = data['имя_файла'].str.replace('YY', str(old_year)).str.replace('ZZ', str(current_year))
data['Значения'] = data['Значения'].str.replace('^', '=', regex=True)
data.sort_values(by='имя_файла', ascending=True, inplace=True)
data.to_excel('unpivot_stack.xlsx', index=False)
log_file = open('log.txt', 'a')
opened_files = {}
 def search_files(current_path, file_name):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(current_path):
        for file in files:
            if file == file_name:
                return os.path.join(root, file)
    return None
def clean_up_memory(workbooks):
    for workbook in workbooks.values():
        workbook.close()
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    путь = row['путь']
    имя_файла = row['имя_файла']
    лист = row['лист']
    ячейки = row['ячейка'].split(',')
    новые_данные = row['Значения']

    if имя_файла not in opened_files:
        target_file_path = search_files(путь, имя_файла)
        if target_file_path is not None:
            workbook = load_workbook(target_file_path)
            opened_files[имя_файла] = workbook
        else:
            print(f"Файл {имя_файла} не найден в папке {путь}. -> продолжаем замену данных...")
            continue
    else:
        workbook = opened_files[имя_файла]
    if лист in workbook.sheetnames:
        sheet = workbook[лист]
        for ячейка in ячейки:
            if ':' in ячейка:
                start_cell, end_cell = ячейка.split(':')
                start_row = int(re.findall(r'\d+', start_cell)[0])
                end_row = int(re.findall(r'\d+', end_cell)[0])
                start_column = 0
                end_column = 0
                for c in re.findall(r'[A-Z]+', start_cell):
                    start_column = start_column * 26 + column_index_from_string(c)
                for c in re.findall(r'[A-Z]+', end_cell):
                    end_column = end_column * 26 + column_index_from_string(c)
                for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=start_row, min_col=start_column, max_row=end_row,max_col=end_column):
                    for cell in row:
                        cell.value = str(новые_данные)
            else:
                sheet[ячейка] = str(новые_данные)
            workbook.save(target_file_path)
            clean_up_memory(opened_files)
    else:
        print(f"Лист {лист} не найден в файле {имя_файла}. -> продолжаем замену данных...")
        continue
log_file.close()
messagebox.showinfo("ОК", "Данные скопированы!")
```

Comment: Пы Сы не обращайте внимание на мелкие огрехи типа 'region_num += 1
        print(f"Колличество сформированных регионов: {region_num}") '- очевидно что эта часть кода должна быть в другом месте!

Comment: Не очень приятно оформленны отступы в вашем коде, прошу вас поправить

Comment: @Эникейщик
Принято! убил все лишнее оставил только функциональные данные! Если в двух словах то у меня сейчас цикл завязан на лист и ячейку внутри файла по списку PD DF после каждого обновления листа с ячейками файл пересохраняется! А нужно сначала обновить все на всех листах и только после сохранить файл! как то так.. В любом случае спасибо за участие!

Comment: Так перенеси workbook.save в конец, после цикла

Comment: @Эникейщик Спасибо но нет это не подходит! Дело в том,  что файлов очень много и если все данные хранить в памяти то в какой то момент мы получаем ошибку памяти.
Я использовал `    for имя_файла, workbook in changed_files.items():
        workbook.save(search_files(group['путь'].iloc[0], имя_файла))
    messagebox.showinfo("ОК", "Данные скопированы!")` в таком случае программа работает быстро но ошибка памяти возникает гораздо быстрее! Резюмируя у меня проблема с очисткой памяти во время выполнения цикла...

Comment: Так же я пробывал  такие решения:         `# count += 1
        # if count % 50 == 0:
        #     for имя_файла, workbook in changed_files.items():
        #         workbook.save(search_files(group['путь'].iloc[0], имя_файла))` но тоже неудачно!

Comment: 1) Не могли бы вы привести в порядок ваш код в вопросе. Очень сложно на самом деле его понять. 2) У вас как я понял в основном цикле, из каждой строки берется название файла и путь к нему. После вызывается функция `search_files` которая по названию ищет файлы, но по факту только путь до 1 файла. И эта функция ищет файл с названием `file_name` начиная с папки `current_path` и во всех подпапках. Это выглядит не очень эффективно. В колонке `путь` записаны пути конкретно до файлов? Или могут быть пути до каких-то родительских папок, в которых нужно находить файл.

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял, у вас есть `xlsx` файл. В нем записаны пути до файлов `xlsx`*, названия файлов, названия листов, ячейки которые нужно изменить в формате** и значения на которые нужно изменить ячейки.

* - именно путь до папки, где нужно искать файл не рассматривая подпапки.

** - формат столбца с ячейками такой. Через запятую перечисляются (или без запятой, если одна ячейка) ячейки, которые могут быть формата одной ячейки или промежуток (через `:`).

И ваша задача, пройтись по всем файлам, которые указаны в главном файле, и поменять значения у указанных ячеек на значение из столбца `"Значения"`.

Далее будут приведены некоторые мои идеи, которые строятся на основе того, что я понял. Если я что-то не так понял, отпишите в комментариях к ответу.

1. Вы можете отсортировать `data` сначала по пути к файлу, а потом по названию файла. Тогда у вас в `data` будут по очереди идти файлы, которые вам нужно изменять. А это значит, что не потребуется хранить `workbook` в `workbooks`.

   Пока вы рассматриваете строки в `data` у которых один путь и одно название файла, у вас все это время открыт один `workbook`. После того как вы переходите к другому файлу (у которого или путь, или название отличается от предыдущей строки), вы сохраняете сначала существующий, а потом создаете новый `workbook`. Это существенно уменьшит количество сохранений.
2. Вам не нужна функция `search_files`, чтобы проверить, что файл существует, можно написать так `os.path.isfile(os.path.join(путь, имя_файла))`.
3. Никогда не работал с `openpyxl`, но немного погуглив) нашел, что по ячейкам можно пройтись таким способом:

   ```py
   for row in sheet[ячейка]:
       for cell in row:
           cell.value = новые_данные
   ```

   То есть без самостоятельного парсинга номера столбца, строки и т.д в блоке `if ':' in ячейка`.

   P.s. у вас и в той реализации, что имеется сейчас, есть по моему мнению непонятные места, где вы например зачем то проходитесь циклом по `re.findall(r'[A-Z]+', start_cell)` хотя точно так же, как и в `start_row` у вас результат будет массив из одного элемента. + непонятные `start_column = start_column * 26 + column_index_from_string(c)` и т.д.
4. Есть у вас нет `workbooks` (см. 1 пункт), то вам и не нужна функция `clean_up_memory` т.к. у вас нет и `opened_files`.

Comment: Спасибо за мысль, я переписал код добавив словарь и переписав цикл замены, в моем коде выше каждый лист каждый раз открывал файл, я переписал цикл что программа открывает файл только один раз - это значительно ускорило процесс замены! Не могу добавить готовый код в коментарий так как он достаточно громоздкий. вот осн. часть:
'for имя, замены in replacements.items():
 target_file_path = search_files(путь, имя_файла)
  for (лист, row, column), новые_данные in замены.items():
   sheet = workbook[лист]
   sheet.cell(row=row, column=column, value=новые_данные)'